# $Y^{\perp} = \{0\}$ is equivalent to $Y=X$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

So I am having trouble proving the following result:
Let $Y$ be a closed linear subspace of a normed vector space $X$. Then $Y^{\perp} = \{0\}$ is equivalent to $Y=X$.

Where $Y^{\perp}$ is the annihilator of the subspace $Y$.

I am trying to use a combination of $(ImT)^\perp = kerT^*$ and the first isomorphism theorem along with T being the quotient map. But I do not seem to be getting anywhere with that approach. Any help or hints would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From another problem posted on this stackexchange we know that $(X/Y)^* \cong Y^\perp$. This in turn implies that $X=Y$. Everything in $X/Y$ gets mapped to $0$ since the only functional in the dual space is $f \equiv 0$. Thus everything in $X$ must also be in $Y$ ($X \subseteq Y$). Since $Y \subseteq X$ is given, we have equality.

The other direction was given by Fred above.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote the topological dual space of $X$ by $X'$.

1. If $Y=X$, then $Y^{\perp}=X^{\perp}=\{f \in X': f(x)=0 \forall x \in X\}=\{0\}.$
2. Let  $Y^{\perp}=\{0\}$ and suppose that $Y \ne X$. Then there is $x_0 \in X$ with $x_0 \notin Y$.

A corollary of the Hahn-Banach Theorem shows, since $Y$ is closed, that there is $f\in X'$ such that

$f(x_0)\ne 0$ and $f(y)=0$ for all $y \in Y$.

Hence $f \ne 0$, but $f \in Y^{\perp}$, a contradiction.

FRED

Comment: how can we guarantee that the zero mapping is the only bounded linear functional that maps everything in X to 0? Couldn't there possibly be another dependent on what type of normed space we are in?

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in X$, then $f$ is the zero mapping.